# angular permission show message and set the button disabled

Tags: angularjs

I'm using  ["angular permission"](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission). I validate the user role and works perfect, but I want to show a message when the user doesn't has these role and if is possible shows the button disabled. Anyone could help me with this?

this is my router definition:

```
 $stateProvider.state('ActionAccess', {url: '/ActionAccess', templateUrl: 'views/ActionAccess.html', controller: 'ActionAccessController', data: { permissions: { only: ['admin'] } } })
```

and this is my function to define if the user has or not the role:

```
.run(function (Permission, authorizationFactory){
  // Define anonymous role
  Permission.defineRole('admin', function (stateParams) {
    return authorizationFactory.isInRole("admin");
  });
})
```

Comment: did you found a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission#setting-route-permissionsroles) on the project page, you can specify this in the router config with the `redirectTo` property.

```
data: {
    permissions: {
      except: ['anonymous'],
      redirectTo: 'login'
    }
  }
```